# Displaying data from json file

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm trying to get content from a json file, but until now I get nothing.

I have the status connection == 200 and I can see the content in the chrome console 
but I get nothing when I try to display the data to html table, but when I use  the same jquery code with api from another service like import.io things works fine.

Can you tell me what am I doing wrong? 
This api is from kimonolabs.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var tabel = '<table><THEAD><caption>Calendário</caption></THEAD>';
    tabel += '<th>' + 'Hora' + '</th>' + '<th>' + 'Equipas' + '</th><th>' + 'jornda' +
        '</th><th>' + 'Data' + '</th>';

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/1dm6b',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);

            $('#update').empty();

            $(data.m_Marcadores).each(function (index, value) {
                tabel += '<tr><td>' + this.posicao + '</td>' + '<td>' + this.golos + '</td></tr>';
            }); //each

            tabel += '</table>';

            $("#update").html(tabel);

        } //data

    }); //ajax
}); //ready
```

Comment: Did you try to debug the 'success' function?

Comment: Tank's  man, you save me, It´s working now. I put only two colunn becouse I was testing.

Comment: Sorry about my inglish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to JSON structure you should iterate over `data.results.m_Marcadores` array:

```
$(data.results.m_Marcadores).each(function (index, value) {
    tabel += '<tr><td>' + this.posicao + '</td><td>' + this.golos + '</td></tr>';
});
```

Another problem. In header of the table you setup 4 colums, but in loop you are creating only two of them. Number of header columns should be the same as other row `td`.

Also you need to wrap `th` elements in `tr`. For example, fixed table header:

```
var tabel = '<table>' +
            '<THEAD><caption>Calendário</caption></THEAD>' +
            '<tr>' + 
                '<th>Hora</th><th>Equipas</th><th>jornda</th><th>Data</th>' + 
            '</tr>';
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/onz02e43/